# Not Able to Take Screenshot on Safari using Grid and RemoteWebDriver

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, safari, selenium-grid

I am trying to get a screenshot from Safari using Grid and RemoteWebDriver. I have tried the following approaches:

1. Using the code below. It works on all browsers except Safari. I also tried returning a BASE64 string but didn't work.

   ```
   WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
   File source = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
   FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("screenshot.png"));
   ```

   `Exception: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException`
2. Using WebDriverBackedSelenium. This throws exception.

   a.

   ```
   Selenium sel = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl());
   sel.captureScreenshot(filename);
   ```

   `Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: captureScreenshot`

   b.

   ```
   Selenium sel = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl());
   sel.captureScreenshotToString();
   ```

   `Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WebDriver does not implement TakeScreenshot`
3. I tried sending the key sequence that takes screen shots in MAC (command+shift+3) using `sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SHIFT, "3"))` but `Keys.COMMAND` is not considered as modifier key so this also didn't work.

After some research I came across the issue below:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4203

I also saw this revision which is suppose to fix the issue but I am not able to figure out how to implement this
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=17731

I would really appreciate if I could get some help on this. I am using MAC, Safari 5.1.7 and selenium 2.25.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: this seems to have been [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4203) in Selenium 2.26